# Why does Wordpress uses HTTPS for JS, CSS on EC2

Tags: ssl, https, http, amazon

I have migrated Wordpress site to EC2.
Domain changes done in wp-config.php & in DB tables
Also set AllowOverride All in Apache sites default conf.

**Issue is:** Even though nowhere I'm using force SSL, still, on page load all assets are loaded with https.
Since, I dont have SSL certificate active, all those resource show ERR_CONNECTION in Browser Console. 
As a result, The Pages also do not render properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason for the Issue was https-redirection plugin. I wasnt aware there was https-redirection plugin installed.
So, even though i checked wp-config.php & .htaccess for SSL redirects, the plugin was forcing SSL for CSS/JSS/images.

I renamed the plugin folder and everything is proper now.

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/https-redirection /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/STOP-https-redirection
```